# Is possibility to set global regexp pattern on springMVC @PathVariable?

Tags: regex, spring, spring-mvc

Like in title, do you know some possibility to set global regexp on all `@PathVariable` in spring under `@RequestMapping`? For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view/{id:[a-z]{5}|[1-9]{7}}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('XXXX')")
    public String viewId(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        ...
    }
```

I do not want to set regexp locally as `{id:[a-z]{5}|[1-9]{7}}`, but I want to set it in may places. Additionally I have configuration, which I don't want to change:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxxx.yyy.zzz.controller.formatters"})
public class MediaPortalWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
@Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }
}
```

So I know what is the meaning of `setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);` and this has to stay in spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom path matcher e.g. `CustomRegexPathMatcher` by extending the default [`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) and overriding its [`doMatch`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html#doMatch-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-java.util.Map-) method so that it consider your regex when performing matching against URL

Than you would include it like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxxx.yyy.zzz.controller.formatters"})
public class MediaPortalWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
@Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setPathMatcher(new CustomRegexPathMatcher());
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }
}
```